# API code behind to add standard "title" tag to template

Tags: docusignapi

In code behind, I'm using the com.docusign.esign.model.Document api to create a document to attach to a com.docusign.esign.model.EnvelopeDefinition.

In the document, I want to add a standard tag to autopopulate the "Title" field so that when the signer goes to the docusign websUI to sign the doc, his Title will be autopopulated (assuming he/she added one in the profile/preferences).

From what I've read, it is not clear to me how to codify the com.docusign.esign.model.Document so that it has the standard "title" tag inside of it.  The  com.docusign.esign.model.Signers object doesn't have a Title property either.

The com.docusign.esign.model.Document is created in Word, then saved locally and finally uploaded to docusign in code behind.  this is not a salesforce solution.

can anyone help?

Comment: Can you please post the code you are having the issue.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the How to Ask page (http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for help clarifying this question